# How to search through a string to see if i can spell a word

Tags: python, string, python-itertools

For instance I have

```
x = "dsjcosnag"
y = "dog"

print(checkYinX(y,x))
>>true
```

So I think I would need to use a while loop as a counter for each of the letter in y, and then I can use itetools to cycle through each of x, each cycle It would check to see if x == y, if it is it would remove it then check the next letter in o.

Is there a more simple way to do this?

Comment: Does the order of letters in `x` matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to convert `x` and `y` to multi-sets, then subtract to see if all of `y`'s letters can be found in `x`:

```
from collections import Counter

def checkYinX(y, x):
    return not (Counter(y) - Counter(x))
```

Subtracting multi-sets *removes* characters when their count falls to 0. If this results in an empty multi-set, it becomes `False` in a boolean context, like all 'empty' python types. `not` turns that into `True` if that is the case.

Demo:

```
>>> x = "dsjcosnag"
>>> y = "dog"
>>> print(checkYinX(y,x))
True
>>> print(checkYinX('cat',x))
False
```

Comment: What is the return 'not' doing? as opposed to just return? I tested it without the not and it just returns counter()

Comment: @jack: The result of the subtraction returns a `Counter()` object. If it is *empty*, `not` returns `True`, otherwise it'll return `False`. Empty objects in python test as `False` in a boolean context.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it without `collections.Counter`, as requested in chat:

```
def countLetters(word):
    d = {}
    for l in word:
        d[l] = d.get(l,0) + 1
    return d

def checkSubset(answer,letters):
    a, l = countLetters(answer), countLetters(letters)
    return all(l.get(x,0) >= a.get(x) for x in a.keys())

print(checkSubset('dog','odr'))
```